# How to pass value to stored procedure with spatial/geography data type using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, geography

I'm a student and after 2H searching answer I'm hopping that someone can help me here.

I created a stored procedure that expects a name, address and geography location then adds a new branch to the `Branches` table. I'm trying to pass a geography value using a new query, but I keep getting a syntax error.

Stored procedure :

```
create procedure AddBranch
    @Name nvarchar(50),
    @Address nvarchar(100),
    @GeographicLocation geography
as
begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    insert into Branches (Name, Address, GeographicLocation)
    values (@Name, @Address, @GeographicLocation)

    select BranchID 
    from Branches 
    where BranchID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
end
```

Query:

```
exec AddBranch 
    @Name = 'Some Name',
    @Address = 'Some Address',
    @GeographicLocation = geography::Point(47.65100, -122.34900, 4326)
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near'::'

Is there a way to pass geography data to a stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to enclosing the arguments in quotes, you need to assign the method result to a local variable in order to pass the value as a parameter in T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @geographyPoint geography = geography::Point('47.65100', '-122.34900', '4326');
exec AddBranch 
    @Name = 'Some Name',
    @Address = 'Some Address',
    @GeographicLocation = @geographyPoint;
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my query.
Now I need to learn how I mark this as my selected answer :)

Answer (score 1):

as a sidenote:

```
create procedure dbo.AddBranch --always specify schema
    @Name nvarchar(50),
    @Address nvarchar(100),
    @GeographicLocation geography
as
begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET XACT_ABORT ON --should be in every data modification SP

    insert into dbo.Branches (Name, Address, GeographicLocation) --schema!
    output inserted.BranchID --this
    values (@Name, @Address, @GeographicLocation)

    select SCOPE_IDENTITY() BranchID  --or this

   --absolutely no need in another read operation from persistent table
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the values into quotes like this

```
exec AddBranch 
@Name = 'Some Name',@Address = 'Some Address',
@GeographicLocation = geography::Point('47.65100', '-122.34900', '4326')
go
```

Although this might not work depending on how this custom `Geography` type expects its values, it will solve the syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I get the same error.
Geography is not my custom type, It was already part of the sql and i just selected it when created the table.

Comment: You tried using `STPointFromText`, like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stpointfromtext-geography-data-type